# How do you use Helvetica and Helvetica Black in C# System.Drawing.Font?

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I did find this [Why is my FontFamily "Arial"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32702528/why-is-my-fontfamily-arial) but it doesn't go into what to do if there is anything you can do.

I tried modifying the registry which I hate and consider that a hack.

I'm trying to use Helvetica and Helvetica Black in code C# new Font(familyName, emSize, FontStyle, GraphicsUnit)

I do have those fonts installed.

EDIT:  I didn't include any code because it's just the new Font method on System.Drawing.

```
var font = new Font("Helvetica", 10, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Millimeter);
```

Although Helvetica and Helvetica Black are installed the above method call returns Arial which I believe is because that's what the Registry says to do and if I ask for Helvetica Black it returns Microsoft Sans Serif which the registry says "Helv" so I'm guessing it's picking up on that.

Even if I tell the registry not to do that I'm still getting those values.

The ultimate goal was to display to the user a list of installed fonts and then allow them to pick ones to use.

Something else I just noticed

```
System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families
```

Returns 237 fonts but Helvetica and Helvetica Black are not listed.

Comment: You might look at [How to manage custom fonts in web application (system.drawing)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3909520/215552) It says "web application" but I don't see anything that requires a web application in the code.

Comment: Show the code you use!

Comment: It is an OpenType font, the kind you can only use in a WPF or UWP app.  Winforms requires TrueType fonts.